# RecyclerView change order Permanently

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I used firebase to retrieve data and display it on RecyclerView. I also used itemtouchhelper simple callback to drag and change the order of the recyclerview. However, the changes made to the recyclerview does not save and resets to the original order. How can I make the change in order last permanently?

---

```
 ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN | ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END, 0) {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        int fromPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        int toPosition = target.getAdapterPosition();

        Collections.swap(List, fromPosition, toPosition);

        adapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

    }
};
```

---

```
  private void loadList() {
    List = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("List");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            List.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot ss: snapshot.getChildren()){
                if(ss.child("moreList").child(ID).exists()){
                    ListModel model = ss.getValue(ListModel.class);
                    List.add(model);
                }
            }
            adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), List);
            RecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
            itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(RecyclerView);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
    
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning `false` in `onMove` function?

Comment: the recyclerview still does not change permanently after I returned true